# Undeletable folders with random name keeps appearing in secondary drive

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, ntfs, external-hdd

I have a NTFS drive used for storage in my system. Folders with names such as `==W0pCl%e+6l7JE=3tYSx.CN0511en9@pAKMQKST=G#LKuwgAo+T4hFlqa6GD=IVjuKnXqrIt62f_BKHmSDOkSJHdT+u@V+9gLRj=YqV4Fw9@ew6KTsNDvvOsHoEarWKV%1CGX@C=#U3%7yM_njeIUfoBtKnmRSmawkSP6Hx.9X4RVg5ZfS3D=9KC#.Dl_AVU0nq%EUXzvG7f_zeE_DKfooGz5#p3yN.#SHhXK5+UAPT5D5h2ct+SYlC4FjEBQT` keeps on appearing on the drive (mounted as a folder).

When I try to delete them, I get an I/O error. When I finally get rid of them with sudo wipe , another one with another random name immediately appears.

Why is this phenomenon occurring, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Who is the owner of the file?  Does it appear in `lsof`? Why are you using NTFS for storage on a Unix/Linux system?

Comment: It appears that I am the owner of the file. Lsof also results im am I/O error. I used to dual boot windows, so it had to be ntfs for me to be able to move files between them.

Comment: You could rename the directory in which the files are appearing, and check your logs for a service or program screaming about being unable to write its file.

Comment: Is there anything stored in these folders?

Comment: Inside the folder is another folder with a random name, and inside that one another folder with a random name (all nested within one another), and so on ... until eventually getting an I/O error and the last nested folder appeared as empty. Very weird.